# CLLocation Manager startUpdatingLocation not starting

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-location

I have been following this tutorial http://www.devfright.com/ios-6-core-location-tutorial/ to add location services to my ios app. I have imported the Corelocation in my TestFileViewController.h file like so:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

 @interface TestFileViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, NSStreamDelegate>

 @property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

 @end
```

and then in the testFileViewController.m ViewDidLoad I added (remembering to implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate):

```
//start checking for location from CoreLocation Framework (currently not working)
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    NSLog(@"location services enabled");
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
};

}
```

(conditional CLLocationManager executes true and NSLogs) and then right below ViewDidLoad:

```
    //fail to find location, handle error
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError         *)error
     {
      NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
      UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [errorAlert show];
      }

      //show found location, return NSLOG for proof
      - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:            (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
      {
      NSLog(@"Made it to location Manager");
      CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

      CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

      NSLog(@"%f",coordinate.latitude);
      }
```

I added the NSLogs just as markers to determine from the console whether or not the functions were being called at all, however neither didFailWithError nor didUpdateToLocation  are called.

Yes I know that didUpdateToLocation is deprecated/outdated, and I replaced it with didUpdateLocations and it still did not work so I changed it back.

How can I get my my locationManager to start updating the current location and return coordinate values in the form of strings to be used later in my app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class a delegate for CLLocationManagerDelegate.

```
@interface TestFileViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, NSStreamDelegate, **CLLocationManagerDelegate**>
```

And then set the delegate to self.

I would also recommend creating a separate class to handle location. Cleaner design.

Also ensure that you are calling startUpdatingLocation on the main thread.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

});
```

Comment: I've added what you suggested and it doesn't seem to change what's happening.

Comment: sorry, to clarify, I made my class a delegate and set the locationManager to call from the testFileViewController.h class, I also removed the locationManager to a method below the view did load and called it from a selector. It still returns that it has enabled location services, however it doesn't actually start updating the location.

Comment: have you put a breakpoint at     [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];? Does it get called? When it does you should see the apple prompt. Did you see that? If not is it possible that you saw it earlier and declined permission? If you go to settings and privacy do you see your app name and perission set  to YES? Help  to help you on a chat window. lmk

Comment: i have added an NSLog in the conditional before it was called, so it is called. I don't see an apple prompt and I am working in the simulator with location enabled so I am not sure how to change the privacy settings.

Comment: Ohh.. in the simulator menu, go to Debug->Location->Select a location. Give it a shot. and for privacy you go to settings->privacy->Location-> you should see your app

Comment: I selected the location using this method and also enabled my location and the locationManager DidUpdateToLocation (DidUpdateLocations) still is not called.

Comment: lets take this offline. if you want we can discuss this here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/57177/locationissue?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

If your are using IOS 8, you should do few things, inorder to make CLlocationManager working.
one do you have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescriptionadded to your apps info.plist file? Two have you set a location in the simulator? (Debug->Location). Third one you must request additional authorisation to use core location in ios8.

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```